# Transform data with NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

What's the best practice with NIFI to extract an attribute in a flowfile and transform it in a Text Format Example :

{ "data" : "ex" }    ===>   My data is ex

How can I do this with NIFI wihtout using a executeScript Processor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use ExtractText to extract the values into attributes. If you added a property in ExtractText like foo = {"(.+)" : "(.+)"} then your flow file would get two attributes for each of the capture groups in the regex:

```
foo.1 = data
foo.2 = ex
```

Then you can use ReplaceText with a Replacement Value of:

```
My ${foo.1} is ${foo.2}
```